# Deleted portion is still showing in the angular app

Tags: html, angularjs, xampp

[image]I am creating an angular app, i just put a thumbnail slider in a page later i removed it. The problem is that html portion of thumbnail is still showing in the page. I've tried everything and at last i pulled the previous version from git there also that portion is showing in local. I'm using Xampp server. Is it a virus? What may be the issue?

Actually this portion is not in the code, but it's still showing, i've deleted the corresponding js files and css too.

Comment: Could you post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), please? Also, hard refresh your page once - `ctrl + F5`.

Comment: @abhig10 updated the question